# Vue 3 - Execute method from another component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

A silly question but I am new to Vue js ...

Hello,

Is there any way to execute a method from another component?

for example I have 2 components

componentOne.vue

```
<template>
  <section>
          <div>Submit</div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  
};
</script>
```

componentTwo.vue

```
<template>
  <section>
          <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
    myMethod() {
      //some code
    },


</script>
```

I want to add a @click listener to the div element from componentOne and execute the method from component Two. Is it that possible somehow ?

I tried to use the $emit method but I think that this is the wrong way to make it work.

Comment: How are these components related: parent-child or siblings?

Comment: Siblings. I render the two components in the app.vue file and both components are located in a src/components folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the recommended way, props down, events up. E.g. you send an emit from componentOne which you catch in the parent and this is setting a prop on componentTwo which has a watch on this prop where you can execute the method.

**parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <componentOne @component-clicked="triggered = true"></componentOne>
  <componentTwo :triggered="triggered"></componentTwo>
</template>

<script setup>
const triggered = ref(false);
</script>
```

**componentOne.vue**

```
<template>
  <section>
          <div @click="emit('component-clicked')">Submit</div>
  </section>
</template>

<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits(['component-clicked']);
</script>
```

**componentTwo.vue**

```
<template>
  <section>
          <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  </section>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    triggered: { type: Boolean}
});
watch(
    () => props.triggered,
    () => {
        if (props.triggered === true) {
            //doStuff
        }
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas!!!Emitting a custom event was the right way to implement after all.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way if you want :

First, you need to register your components globally:

[Register your components globally](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html)

Then in any component you can do :

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

const vm = getCurrentInstance();

vm?.appContext.app.component('MyComponent')?.call('MyMethod', ['myparameters']);
```

In your template :

```
<template>
  <Component1 @click="vm.appContext.app.component('Component2 ')?.call('MyMethod', ['myparameters'])"/>
  <Component2 />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a context to register componentTwo to componentOne, and then you can excute componentTwo's method inside componentOne

Answer (score -2):

Do you want to do this without rendering the `componentTwo`? if yes, I am not sure if that is possible. If you are rendering the component you give it a `ref`, grab that ref in your script and call the method on that.